# PHP/MYSQL : Dynamic jquery group lightbox images

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, smarty, adodb

i have this jquery function for show image gallery when click in button (static image). so this worked 100% for me :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#gallery").click(function() {
      $.lightbox(["assets/4.jpg", "assets/3.jpg", "assets/6.jpg"]);
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

now i have dynamic image gallery using `PHP` / `MySQL` / `smarty` / `ADODB`.

my PHP Code is :

```
$aid        = intval($aid);
$sql            = "SELECT PID, caption FROM photos WHERE AID = " .$aid. " AND status = '1' LIMIT " .$limit;
$rs             = $conn->execute($sql);
$photos         = $rs->getrows();
$smarty->assign('photo', $photos);
// Other Smarty Engine Code
```

My TPL smarty is :

```
{if $photos}
{section name=i loop=$photos}
<img src="{$relative}/media/photos/tmb/{$photos[i].PID}.jpg" alt="{$photos[i].caption|escape:html}" width="160" height="120" id="album_photo_{$photos[i].PID}" />
{/section}
{/if}
```

Now! i need To Generate/Print loop img Address to jquery `function($lightbox(["dynamic.jpg","dynamic1.jpg","dynamic2.jpg"]);)` for dynamic jquery lightbox group.

How To generate this?! Thanks For Any Idea & help.

Comment: How to fix what? You have not given any error message. If you have no clue how to use the components you use, you need to learn them first. If that was what you're asking for.

Comment: I'd say you need to change the smarty template. But isn't that obvious? Don't you know what a smarty template is probably and how it works? And if you are only concerned about the output, why do you put so much code into your question. What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Exactly. So I wrote some code For a better understanding ( how to work my codes).In fact I need something else

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
{if $photos}
$.lightbox(["{"\", \""|implode:$photos}"]);
{/if}
```

Comment: in My Page result/print is : $.lightbox(["Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array"]); This True But i have two question : how to put this in jquery function using smarty? how to array to really address `({$relative}/media/photos/tmb/{$photos[i].PID}.jpg)`?

Comment: That is because the `$photos` variable must be an array or arrays. Assign a new array, containing just the filenames, and use the same code as per above.